# Ubuntu 18.04 server: Temporary failure in name resolution (LAN only)

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, dns

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04 server and I cannot ping by hostname inside my own LAN.
The installer updated to the new installer version before performing the install.

```
ping: rpi3: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

- Ubuntu is able to ping everything by IP inside local LAN
- Ubuntu is able to ping www.google.com
- Ubuntu is unable to ping anything (firewall, windows pc, raspberry pi) by hostname inside LAN
- Windows PC is able to ping ubuntu by hostname
- Windows PC is able to ping rpi3 by hostname

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my MacBook Pro 2012 (home), Hyper-V (home) and VMware vSphere (company).
The error persists through all of these installs.

### What I tried

- changing the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
- changing /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and restarting systemd-resolved
- disabling systemd-resolved completely

## Here is some information

**ip address show**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:dd:a8:c4:6b:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.3/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global enp1s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::12dd:b1ff:fec4:6bbc/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**ip route**

```
default via 192.168.10.1 dev enp1s0f0 proto static
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp1s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.3
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

**/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml**

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp1s0f0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.10.3/24
            gateway4: 192.168.10.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.10.1
    version: 2
```

**/etc/resolv.conf (symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf)**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

**systemd-resolve --status**

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 192.168.10.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      (and so many more)
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp1s0f0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.10.1
```

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**nslookup ubuntu.com**

```
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.44
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.180
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.91.45
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 91.189.88.181
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::1f
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1360:8001::2c
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1562::20
Name:   ubuntu.com
Address: 2001:67c:1360:8001::2b
```

**dig ubuntu.com**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.11-Ubuntu <<>> ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18380
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 4, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ubuntu.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ubuntu.com.             575     IN      A       91.189.91.44
ubuntu.com.             575     IN      A       91.189.88.181
ubuntu.com.             575     IN      A       91.189.91.45
ubuntu.com.             575     IN      A       91.189.88.180

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 29 21:28:12 CEST 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

Comment: I've temporarily added my local DNS server address to `/etc/resolv.conf` and the problem has solved. I know it's not a nice approach, however, it resolved.

Comment: @M.Rostami I already changed the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf, but this seems to be ignored completely, even after rebooting. Also, /etc/resolv.conf is nothing more than a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf (changed that too, didn't help).

Comment: @HamsDa were you able to resolve that?

Comment: @Putnik I'm sorry but it's been too long, I can't remember =/

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue