# Ubuntu 20.04 server: Temporary failure in name resolution (LAN only)

Tags: dns

This issue is exactly the same as this:
[Ubuntu 18.04 server: Temporary failure in name resolution (LAN only)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233105/ubuntu-18-04-server-temporary-failure-in-name-resolution-lan-only)

except that we are on 20.04.  So problem still exists.

My resolution was the same as M. Rostami Jul 1 '20 at 6:09, edit the /etc/resolv.conf file and correct the nameserver there.

It works now, but that seems like the wrong solution?  I thought that Ubuntu no longer used that file?  That does not appear to be the case.

Thanks.

Bryan Hunt

Comment: I had a similar or the same issue, and found that I could hit up my local server using "name.local" instead of just "name". Does that apply?